# NetCDF: Get lat, lon from variable into dimensions

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

I have a NetCDF file with two variables float_latitude and float_longitude for the lats and lons. In the dimensions, I have, besides the time dim, a column and a row. How can I get the lat and lon as dimensions? Is this possible via xarray?

Here is the metadata from the file:

```
netcdf file:Polar-APP-X_v02r00_Shem_1400_d20091230_c20190625.nc {
  dimensions:
    columns = 321;
    rows = 321;
    Time = 1;
  variables:
    float cdr_surface_temperature(Time=1, columns=321, rows=321);
      :_FillValue = 9999.0f; // float
      :standard_name = "surface_temperature";
      :long_name = "NOAA CDR of surface skin temperature";
      :valid_range = 0.0f, 1000.0f; // float
      :units = "K";
      :grid_mapping = "crs";
      :coverage_content_type = "physicalMeasurement";
      :coordinates = "longitude latitude time";
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 321U, 321U; // uint

    float latitude(columns=321, rows=321);
      :_FillValue = NaNf; // float
      :standard_name = "latitude";
      :long_name = "latitude of EASE Grid 25km resolution in the polar regionsArctic (361,361), Antarctic (321,321)";
      :units = "degrees_north";

    float longitude(columns=321, rows=321);
      :_FillValue = NaNf; // float
      :standard_name = "longitude";
      :long_name = "longitude of EASE Grid 25km resolution in the polar regions, Arctic (361,361), Antarctic (321,321)";
      :units = "degrees_east";

    double time(Time=1);
      :_FillValue = NaN; // double
      :standard_name = "time";
      :long_name = "days since 2009-01-01 00:00:00";
      :axis = "T";
      :units = "days since 2009-01-01";
      :calendar = "proleptic_gregorian";

    float cdr_surface_albedo(Time=1, columns=321, rows=321);
      :_FillValue = 9999.0f; // float
      :standard_name = "surface_albedo";
      :long_name = "NOAA CDR of surface broadband albedo";
      :valid_range = 0.0f, 1.0f; // float
      :units = "1";
      :grid_mapping = "crs";
      :coverage_content_type = "physicalMeasurement";
      :coordinates = "longitude latitude time";
      :_ChunkSizes = 1U, 321U, 321U; // uint

  // global attributes:
  :standard_name = "surface_albedo";
  :long_name = "NOAA CDR of surface broadband albedo";
  :valid_range = 0.0f, 1.0f; // float
  :units = "1";
  :grid_mapping = "crs";
  :coverage_content_type = "physicalMeasurement";
}
```

Comment: Could you open the file with xarray and show how that looks?

Comment: What do you mean? Just displaying the metadata with printing the dataset or do you meaning plotting the data?

Comment: Basically just `ds = xr.open_dataset(filename); print(ds)`